# Is Xamarin perfect tool for a Camera Surveillance application?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I am having experience in iOS application development in native platform and tools. I have a requirement to port an existing native application to Xamarin platform so that it is only a matter to maintain single code base for multiple platforms. My existing application has following features.

- Api calls using AFNetworking Library.
- Local caching of data using
  Core Data, NSIncremental Store. Core Data migrations are implemented
  to support versioning. Also complex mappings are done using many-many
  relationship, one-many relationship etc.
- Asynchronous and
  synchronous network calls.
- Listing items using table view controller
  with Search Controller. Pagination is implemented in these view
  controllers.
- One of the views in the application is rendered using
  Open GL.

Can all these features be perfectly ported to Xamarin. Does Xamarin provide apis for these features? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let me tell you that Xamarin is not about a single code base for all the three platforms, but you could share a good amount of code between the three platforms. But that will depend on each app.

To the best of my Knowledge AFNetworking has a partial support. This is repo for it: https://github.com/paulcbetts/AFNetworking-Xamarin . But if you plan to port your app to xamarin/ cross platform. I would recommnend using a C# variant, check if Modernhttpclient will help you?

Local data caches are very well supported
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleStorage/
https://github.com/akavache/Akavache

Async progrmamming is one of the strengths of C#/xamarin.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/

TableViewController and Pagination is supported

Hope it helps you to get started with porting your app.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using any third party libraries you shouldn't have any problems porting this application to Xamarin.

Before you begin I would advise that you think about any functionality that you can wrap up in a core project and inherit in your iOS and Android projects so that you have the maximum amount of code re-use. Thinking ahead will save you a lot of time.

Also be cautious when using table and collection views. I've previously encountered a solution which was holding on to a lot of memory because the table view cells weren't being deallocated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you are having experience in iOS application development in native platform and tools. there is going to be a huge learning curve.

Shifting from Android studio to Xamarin(VS2015) was a hectic job for me.

But maintaining the less code for multiple devices is really fun using Xamarin.

your first requirement is answered by this [github link here](https://github.com/paulcbetts/AFNetworking-Xamarin)

Asynchronous and synchronous network calls are easy to handle as I am using it in my project so that is not going to be the problem.

> Happy Coding